# Why do the Laplacian and creation operator commute in second quantisation?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, field-theory, fourier-transform, second-quantization

I am specifically asking this question in regard to showing that the first and second quantisation hamiltonian coincide. Namely, we want to show that
$$H = \int dx\, a^\dagger(x)(-\nabla^2)a(x)$$
is equivalent to the standard Hamiltonian in the position basis $H = -\sum_{i=1}^n\nabla_i^2$. Here, we define $\lvert\psi\rangle = \int d^nx\, \psi(x_1, ..., x_n,t)\prod^n_{i=1}a^\dagger(x_i)\lvert0\rangle$. Also, I haved used the notational convention that $a(x) = \sum_k \chi_k(x)a_k$ and $a^\dagger(x) = \sum_k \chi_k^*(x)a_k^\dagger$ are the field operators with $\chi_k$ an eigenfunction of the position basis Hamiltonian.

In this derivation, one ends up at some point with the following expression
$$H\lvert\psi\rangle = \int d^nx \left[\sum_{j=1}^na^\dagger(x_j)(-\nabla_j^2)\psi(x_1, ..., x_n ,t)\prod^n_{j=1,\\i\neq j}a^\dagger(x_i)\right]\lvert0\rangle,$$
which is nearly what we desire, except that we need to swap the dagger operator and the derivatives. In the solutions I have, it is said this is allowed due to these two operators acting on different spaces. But I do not understand why this is the case or what even is meant by the fact that they act on different spaces.

Comment: @CosmasZachos I understand. The material I am working with is based on Quantum Field Theory by Mark Sredniki. He leaves a calculation similar to the above as an exercise to the reader in the first chapter. Specifically, exercise 1.2.

Comment: Doing the *n* =1 first, you see that you need the Laplacians to act on the ψ s and not the *a* s... I think the double-duty notation is magnificently unfortunate. It's much clearer in other QFT books or Wikipedia...

Comment: @CosmasZachos In what sense do we have notation doing double duty here? Would you perhaps have an explicit source where the above is explained clearer?

Comment: Perhaps Sakurai's Advanced QM, sec 3-10, but he does this for fermions, although it also works for bosons. Your fist task is to look at *one* oscillator, *n* =1, and see how your symbols are defined; you are looking at its first excited state wavefunction.

Comment: You might, or might not, wish to review the connection between coordinate space for the ***first*** excited state like your case, for just *one* particle in [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator#Analytical_questions) .

Comment: Ah, I finally understand it. One should truly carry out the derivation so that one just has a number and then the order can be switched. Thank you.